# Wordpress Archive Page for a custom taxonomy element

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type `clientgallery` and the custom taxonomy `client`.

To get all galleries I can type website.com/clientgallery.

But I want to show only galleries of a specific client, like: website.com/clientgallery/miller

So, `miller` should act like a get parameter.

I already know how to get the galleries by client, but I don't know how to get the parameter part working.

```
$args = array(
  'numberposts'     => -1, //limit the number of posts, set 0 if no limit required.
  'orderby'         => 'post_date', //order by post_date field.
  'order'           => 'DESC', //order by descending oder.
  'post_type'       => 'clientgallery', //the post type is custom post type 'News & Events'
  'post_status'     => 'publish', //post status is 'publish'
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'client', //custom taxonomy slug
      'field' => 'slug', //select taxonomy term by slug
      'terms' => $_GET['client'] //taxonomy term is called 'home-page'
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your taxonomy client is only associated with the clientgallery post type, then website.com/client/miller should suffice to show your list of clientgalleries for this client. I tested it on my site, it works. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: thank you for your answer! do you know how to name the archive template for this? archive-client.php does not work

Answer (score 2):

Call it taxonomy-client.php :
See all info here on template hierarchy for WordPress : http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png